# How to assign particular parameters on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, optional-parameters

I have a file called `test.js` which has 2 input argument with some difficult value, I want to call this file from another node js file but I just want to assign to the second parameter without assigning the first parameter. do you have any idea how to do this?

test.js

```
const first= process.argv[2] || "one";
const second= process.argv[3] || "two";

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

another.js

```
const child = require('child_process');
child.execFileSync('node', [
        'test.js',
        'second parameter'

    ],
    {stdio: ['ignore', 1, 2]}
);
```

current result:

```
$ node another.js
second parameter
two
```

expected result:

```
$ node another.js
one
second parameter
```

Comment: You have to achieve the functionality you want in `test.js`

Comment: Can u add the correct file contents of both you `test.js` and `another.js`? Unable to run your program

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality you have to do this in `test.js`. 
You can do it something like:-

```
//initialize with default values
let first = 'one', second = 'two';    
if (process.argv[3]) { // if has 2nd argument
    first = process.argv[2];
    second = process.argv[3];
}
else { // else we assign second to 1st argument
    second = process.argv[2];
}
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first argument is optional. It is a good practice to move optional arguments to the end of the list. So, one of the possible solutions would be to swap your arguments.

Another way of solving this problem is by using named arguments like this:

```
node another.js --bar="second parameter" --foo="first parameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.

a.js

```
const child = require('child_process');
child.execFileSync(
    'node',
    ["test.js",'','2nd param'],
    { stdio: ['ignore',1,2] }
);
```

test.js

```
const first= process.argv[2] || "one";
const second= process.argv[3] || "two";

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

```
node --version
v12.2.0

node a.js
one
2nd param
```

This assigns an empty string to the first parameter and passes your test.

It passes your test because `process.argv[2]` will be the empty string `''`, which is `falsey`, and is replaced by the default `"one"`

Replacing the blank first parameter `''` with `null`, `undefined`, or using `,,` actually sends the strings `'null'` or `'undefined'` as the first parameter, which will not pass your test.